# Extend canvas around image

Tags: php

I've got this code. My problem, that it doesn't work correctly. It extends canvas around image, but image "deformed". I don't know where is it the problem?!

```
$width = 100;
$height = 80;

//$source_width = 50;
//$source_height = 30;

if ($width > $source_width AND $height > $source_height) 
{
$width_new = $width;
$height_new = $height;
$dst_x = ($width - $source_width)/2;
$dst_y = ($height - $source_height)/2;
}
$img = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($img, 0, 0, $white);
imagecopyresampled($img, $source_image, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $width_new, $height_new, $source_width, $source_height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your destination height and width are larger than the source height and width. Make them the same.

You should only use the larger height and width for the canvas (the white)

For example:

```
imagecopyresampled($img, $source_image, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $width_new, $height_new, $source_width, $source_height);
```

Should be:

```
imagecopyresampled($img, $source_image, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $source_width, $source_height, $source_width, $source_height);
```

Comment: Sure. I will publish it)